# Can we register global hotkeys for a browser

Tags: windows, hotkeys, keyboard-shortcuts, global-hotkey

We want to register browser events even when the browser is minimized or not in focus. For example, suppose we are doing something in Microsoft Word and if we press a key on the keyboard (which is not associated with any shortcut of Word or the Windows OS), it should open a new tab in Google Chrome.

Comment: Imagine if Web pages could do this: It would be possible to write a Web page that was a keylogger.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be browser specific. You'll need to create an XPCOM plug-in for Firefox, native app for Chrome, extension for IE, etc. This browser specific add-on will have to register each hotkey with the Windows API and then handle hotkey events as you desire; this of course means you will need to use a language that can access the Windows API. Depending on what you want to automate in the browser you might need to create an additional plugin in pure javascript to gain full access to the browser API.